ClassNotFoundException when calling java code from a different folder than the one holding the code
The problem
I want to run java code from the command line, and I don't understand why I manage to do that from within the folder holding the code, but not from another folder. I am on Windows and am using Cygwin.
Example 1: What works
The folder /usr/local/lib/mytoolfolder/ contains two folders with java code:

mytool/(containing the class I want to run)
utils/ (containing dependencies)

If I do
$ cd /usr/local/lib/mytoolfolder/
$ java -cp ".;utils/bin;utils/lib/*;mytool/bin;mytool/lib/*" mytool.MyTool

... the class MyTool is called without any problems, and I get the expected output.
Example 2: What does not work
If I cd to a random other folder on my computer and try to call MyTool again, now including the full paths in the class path, like so:
$ java -cp "/usr/local/lib/mytoolfolder/.;/usr/local/lib/mytoolfolder/utils/bin;/usr/local/lib/mytoolfolder/utils/lib/*;/usr/local/lib/mytoolfolder/mytool/bin;/usr/local/lib/mytoolfolder/mytool/lib/*" mytool.MyTool

... I get this ClassNotFoundException:
Error: Could not find or load main class mytool.MyTool
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mytool.MyTool

What I have tried
I have checked that the classpaths are correct and I have checked permissions.
Question
I understand that this error means that java can't find the class (obviously). I assume that this is because there is something wrong with the classpath (as Example 1 rules out that there is something wrong with the code itself).
I don't understand WHAT is wrong with the classpath, or with this approach. Where is the flaw in my logic? And how can I make it work?
Additional tips to debug this further are also appreciated.
EDIT
As requested by g00se below -- the output of find /usr/local/lib/mytoolfolder -name \*.jar -o -name \*.class looks like this (the actual output contains more of the same because my example above is minimised):
/usr/local/lib/mytoolfolder/mytool/bin/mytool/MyTool$Connection.class
/usr/local/lib/mytoolfolder/mytool/bin/mytool/MyTool.class
/usr/local/lib/mytoolfolder/utils/bin/tools/math/StatUtils.class
/usr/local/lib/mytoolfolder/utils/bin/tools/path/PathTools$1.class
/usr/local/lib/mytoolfolder/utils/bin/tools/path/PathTools.class
...
/usr/local/lib/mytoolfolder/utils/bin/tools/text/StringTools.class
/usr/local/lib/mytoolfolder/utils/bin/tools/ToolBox.class
/usr/local/lib/mytoolfolder/utils/bin/tools/ToolBox.class
/usr/local/lib/mytoolfolder/utils/lib/jackson-annotations-2.17.1.jar
/usr/local/lib/mytoolfolder/utils/lib/jackson-core-2.17.1.jar
/usr/local/lib/mytoolfolder/utils/lib/jackson-databind-2.17.1.jar


Please don't post the same question again.  Edit the original to improve it.

Can you post the output of find /usr/local/lib/mytoolfolder -name \*.jar -o -name \*.class into the question please

@g00se The OP is trying to run Windows Java under Cygwin, with all the attendant problems.  It may work with relative classpaths, since Java is forgiving about path delimiters, but not absolute Cygwin paths.  This is a dup of the OP's previous question https://stackoverflow.com/q/78630496/18157

Yes I see. But tbh the paths seem quite tortuous even without the Cygwin considerations. Also launching a Java app is being made a lot more difficult than it need be

@JimGarrison My thoughts were that I simplified the question so much that it was no longer the same as the other one, so I opened a new one. The other one has been closed, BTW. Would you suggest I delete it? Also: the reply you give to g00se could actually be quite helpful to me! Could you elaborate?

You can quite easily just create an executable jar. I can't tell you how until you post the output I asked for

Cygwin paths are not same as Windows paths, maybe this helps for conversion

You don't need the /. at the end of the one path, and you need to convert the paths to Windows paths either by hand or with cygpath -w "$path"; you need to do that to each part of the classpath and then reassemble them; cygpath won't do the whole classpath.

To clarify, when you write /usr/foo a Cygwin program, via cygwin1.dll, interprets that as something like (probably) C:/cygwin/usr/foo (depending on where you have Cygwin installed), but a Windows program, like java.exe, treats it as C:/usr/foo (or on whatever drive you happen to be on, maybe F:/usr/foo), so it's not going to find the same thing, or even anything.

All paths given to a Java program must be Windows paths.  The fact that it worked with relative paths is a quirk of Windows Java's tolerance for both forwardslash and backslash as path delimiters.  Windows Java does not and will never understand Cygwin paths.

Yes you've got quite a few jars in there, but not a massive number. A good candidate for a 'fat jar' which you can run thus java -jar x.jar. You can make that with a tool like Maven Shade

java is a Windows program so it doesn't understand Unix-style paths. Cygwin comes with a utility, cygpath that will convert paths, either individually, or even an entire PATH-style path, with the -p switch. But, it expects such a path to be delimited by colons. It will turn it into a Windows-style semicolon-delimited path.
So you could use:
cygpath -pw "/usr/local/lib/mytoolfolder:/usr/local/lib/mytoolfolder/utils/bin:/usr/local/lib/mytoolfolder/utils/lib/*:/usr/local/lib/mytoolfolder/mytool/bin:/usr/local/lib/mytoolfolder/mytool/lib/*"

to convert the path, or even:
java -cp "$(cygpath -pw '/usr/local/lib/mytoolfolder:/usr/local/lib/mytoolfolder/utils/bin:/usr/local/lib/mytoolfolder/utils/lib/*:/usr/local/lib/mytoolfolder/mytool/bin:/usr/local/lib/mytoolfolder/mytool/lib/*")"  mytool.MyTool

to run your program.
